# I tried to push my laravel project and got "remote unpack failed: error Out of memory loading unknown object"

Tags: laravel, git, gitbucket

I tried to push my laravel project to my gitBucket repo and I got this error
"remote unpack failed: error Out of memory loading unknown object"
I searched on internet and I found about JVM heap size from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19563-01/819-4438/gavou/index.html
from that I have question, Must it solved by the owner of repository project?

I will greatly appreciate all help

Comment: GitBucket (according to the tag info) uses Scala, not Java, but in general "out of memory" means whatever program (in this case, on the GitBucket server) you're using has run out of allocated resources. Why *that* is the case is potentially enormously complicated but is completely out of your hands, unless you're the operator of the GItBucket server.

Comment: In short: contact your GitBucket support people and ask *them*.

Answer (score 0):

As that documentation describes, you can increase the heap size by specifying `-Xmx` option if sufficient amount of memory is available on your machine:

```
$ java -Xmx8g -jar gitbucket.war
```